# How can I create a table which accounts the number of each word in a text?

Tags: java

```
package entrainementTPNote2;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class UtilisationCollections {
    static String texte = "bonjour je m'appelle ";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    TableauDeMots();
}
public static void TableauDeMots() {
    char[] TableauDeMots = new char[2000];
    int cpt = 0;
    int i =0;
    for(int k = 0; k < texte.length(); k ++) {
        if(texte.charAt(k) == ' ') {
            cpt+=1;
            int j = k;
            i++;
            while(texte.charAt(j-1) != ' ' && j>1) {
                TableauDeMots[i-1] += (texte.charAt(j-1));
                j--;
               }
            }
       }    
       System.out.println(Arrays.toString(TableauDeMots));
    }

}
```

I want to write a code which permits me to have a table with all the words of a text inside. But when I run this code, it returns a table of 2000 characters, but with values of : [C@7291c18f, for example. I am a beginner in programmation, please, can you help me about this problem. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `TableauDeMots[i-1]` is a char, `texte.charAt(j-1)` is a char, why are you adding them together

Comment: (I do believe that there is a stack overflow website for people who speak french) `TableauDeMots[i-1] += (texte.charAt(j-1));` I would not recommend this. Why are you adding `char`s? This takes their [ASCII](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html) value, adds them, and then casts them back to characters. For example, if `TableauDeMots[i-1] == 'A'` and `texte.charAt(j-1) == 'B'` then `TableauDeMots[i-1] + (texte.charAt(j-1)) == 131` which is above any of the characters listed in the ASCII table.

Comment: What is your code supposed to do? What is the point of it? Also, consider `String.toCharArray()` and the `=` sign. One thing you can do: `char[] c = texte.toCharArray();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want words you should use `String` instead of `char`:

```
String[] TableauDeMots
```

Then you don't have to scan whole text to search for spaces. You can use `split` to divide text and have it stored into an array.
It's sufficient to do something like this:

```
public static void TableauDeMots() {
    String[] tableauDeMots = texte.split(" ");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tableauDeMots));
}
```

Comment: Okay, the code works, thank you a lot. In fact, it's much easier with the predefined method .split () .